# Can I get the Ubuntu Software center in KDE?

Tags: software-center, kubuntu

Is there a way to get the Ubuntu Software Center on Kubuntu?

Comment: Muon constantly crashes in Kubunbtu. I'm trying the Ubuntu software center in Kubuntu and it seems to be working well!

Comment: Updated answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/788554/can-i-get-ubuntu-software-on-kubuntu-16-04?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Be prepared for gtk packages.

Comment: You could use sudo apt-get install software-center --no-install-recommends from a terminal to not get the recommends.

Comment: GTK? I need that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Muon instead of USC. It is very similar and uses the same ratings system.

See the ppa here: [link](https://launchpad.net/~echidnaman/+archive/qapt-experimental).

Answer (score 2):

Apper looks like its just like Muon Software Center which is part of Kubuntu 12.04.

If you want to install the Ubuntu Software Center under Kubuntu without the Gnome recommended packages tacked on run this in your terminal:

`sudo apt-get install software-center --no-install-recommends`

I use UCS primarily to re-install purchased apps without going the long route of finding the private ppa and loading it that way under Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Software Center, but Apper is better for KDE.

Open Konsole and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install apper
```

then enter your password.

If it asks you `Do you want to continue (Y/n)?` enter `y`. Apper will be installed.
You can launch it with Kickoff or by pressing Alt+F2 and typing `apper`.

If you want to install Software Center open Konsole and enter

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

then enter your password.