# Is Lubuntu the only derivative with its own software center?

Tags: software-center, lubuntu

I've noticed that Lubuntu has its own Software Center application, which seems a bit less taxing on my poor netbook than the vanilla SC.

Is Lubuntu the only derivative that takes this approach, or are there other derivatives with their own Software Centers?

Also, are there any Software Center alternatives that are not pre-installed in any official Ubuntu derivative, but which are available in the repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See this: [Can I get the Ubuntu Software center in KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47321/can-i-get-the-ubuntu-software-center-in-kde). It mentions Apper and Muon for Kubuntu.
2. AFAIK, Xubuntu uses the same software center as Ubuntu.
3. My *feeling* is that the last part of your question is off-topic but see this: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2012-October/002871.html. I don't even want to summarize it.
4. Further development of the Lubuntu Software Center [requires helping hands](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2122031)!

*BTW, The Synaptic Package Manager is included by default with Lubuntu and may be even less taxing on your system even though it packs in a vast amount of functionality (without pretty pictures)*.