# Can I get Ubuntu Software on Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu

I am trying out Kubuntu 16.04 moving from Ubuntu 16.04. And I am wondering if it is possible to get the NEW Ubuntu Software Center on Kubuntu 16.04.

I know that you can download the old Software Center but can I download the new one and will it work?

If yes, please, also show me how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a **Konsole** window and type the following line:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-software
```

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the gray checkmark next to it, that way other people can see at a glance that your issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

It is called gnome-software: `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install gnome-software`